# Create an advanced and complete search

Tags: entities, search, views

I want create an advanced and complete search, like the one on http://www.lib.muohio.edu.

I want to enable search in my CCK fields.
I don't know what module this site use; please help me to know that module(s) used in this site.

Help me to style my site like this site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they use the [multifacet](http://code.google.com/p/multifacet/) module.
As for "help me to style like this site,“ that's a very broad request.

Comment: search module is more important for me!please help me.